# how can I change my settings of project for start it in cypress

Tags: node.js, npm, cypress, npm-start

I have a question. I have two projects in Cypress, one I open using `npm run open` without any problem.

[image]

The second project is new and if I enter the command npm run open in its directory, nothing will happen.

[image]

Where do I need to add it so I can run it as well?

Comment: From the screenshots, it looks like your first project has a package.json with a defined "open" script, but it must be missing in your other project's package.json.

Comment: More details about package.json scripts here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I've already figured it out in part. However, the problem is as follows -

> **'cypress' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file."**

. I don't know if it's a problem in PATH or elsewhere. Any advice on that?

[image]

The code from package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "registr-smluv",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cypress run --record --key 2bcf59a3-6c32-4fd7-b201-e9fa14feaa18",
    "open": "cypress open"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^9.2.0",
    "cypress-file-upload": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "puppeteer": "^13.0.1"
  }
}
```